# Não consigo criar tabela no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma instância do SQL SERVER instalada localmente onde sou administrador, consigo criar databases porém não consigo criar tabelas. 
Aqui vai uma foto do erro que o SQL exibe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais Alguns Detalhes:

```
===================================

Erro não especificado
 (MS Visual Database Tools)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataTools.Interop.IDTTableDesignerFactory.NewTable(Object dsRef, Object pServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.TableDesignerNode.CreateDesigner(IDTDocToolFactoryProvider factoryProvider, IVsDataConnection dataConnection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.CreateDesigner()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn, IManagedConnection mc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
```

Comment: Acabei de realizar uma tentativa por script e funcionou, esse erro parece estar relacionado ao contextMenu para criar tabelas e também visões.

Comment: Elabore uma resposta sua para a questão então ;)

Comment: Mas eu não resolvi o problema, somente consegui criar o que eu queria, o problema persiste.

Comment: Ok, então aguardemos uma resposta válida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Quando procuramos demais não vemos o que está bem à nossa frente".

Estava usando o Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express versão 9.**.****.**, que é próprio para uso com instâncias do SQL SERVER 2005.

Recentemente havia instalado uma versão do Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, mas como estava conseguindo criar os bancos nessa instância que começa com 10.*.****.* através do Management Studio não estava tendo problemas.

Mas quando precisei criar estruturas de tabelas e visões apresentava o erro devido ao fato dessa versão do Management Studio ser incompatível com novos recursos adicionados ao SQL SERVER 2008.

Com a instalação do SQL Server Management Studio Express versão 10.**.****.** consegui resolver meu problema e acessar normalmente as instância que já tinha do SQL SERVER 2005, sem nenhum problema de compatibilidade.